# How to connect to a sql database from a device connected to a different network

Tags: database, postgresql, flutter, dart

I am developing an app with a login system in flutter. Using postgresql I can access to an external database located in a raspberry. All works perfect until the network of the device changes. So here are my questions:

- How can I access to a database from a device connected to a different network? Is that possible?
- If not, how could it be the correct way to do it? or what should I read and/or learn to apply this funcionality?

Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like a networking question. Find a way to make the target database available at the network level (i.e. run it on a "public" IP, configure port forwarding on the router of the network in which it's running, etc.)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is not Postgres specific.

You connect to servers over TCP/IP protocol using servers IP address or it's FQDN, fully qualified domain name. If your device is mobile and changes network, you can use some dynamic IP service or your own name servers.

Setting up a port forwarding system is also possible.